# Backbone architecture and view management

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, memory-management, backbone-views

I am struggling with when to destroy backbone views. I know I need to destroy the view somewhere, but I am not sure where.
I have the following code in router.js

```
 routes: {
        "names/search": "nameSearch",
        "companies/search": "companySearch"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        Backbone.history.start();
        this.navigate("#/", true);
    }
    nameSearch: function () {
        require(["app/views/RecordSearch"], function (RecordSearchView) {
            var obj = {};
            obj.Status = [utils.xlate("On Assignment"), utils.xlate("Candidate")];
            var view = new RecordSearchView({ model: obj, el: $(".content") }, { "modelName": "Candidate" });
            view.delegateEvents();
        });
    },
    companySearch: function () {
        require(["app/views/RecordSearch"], function (RecordSearchView) {
            var view = new RecordSearchView({ model: {}, el: $(".content") }, { "modelName": "Company" });
            view.delegateEvents();
        });
    }
```

And then in RecordSearchView.js I have the following function that is called when a user clicks the search button

```
    doSearch: function () {
        require(["app/utils/SearchHelper", "app/models/" + modelName, "app/views/SearchResults"], function (SearchHelper, Model, SearchResultsView) {
            var obj = $("#searchForm").serializeArray();
            var params = SearchHelper.getQuery(obj);
            params["page"] = 1;
            params["resultsPerPage"] = 25;
            var collection = new Model[modelName + "Collection"]({}, { searchParams: params });
            params["Fields"] = collection.getSearchFields();
            collection.getPage(params["page"], function (data) {
                require(["app/views/SearchResults"], function (SearchResultsView) {
                    App.Router.navigate(modelName + "/search/results");
                    var view = new SearchResultsView({ collection: data, el: $(".content") });
                    view.delegateEvents();
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
```

And SearchResults.js

```
return BaseView.extend({

    init: function () {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        var data = this.collection.convertToSearchResults();
        this.$el.html(template(data));
        return this;
    } 
});
```

The problem is the second time I perform any search (calling the doSearch function from RecordSearch.js).  As soon as I perform the second search, the data shown is that belonging to the previous search I performed. (For example I do a name search and it works, then do a company search but the screen shows company search results but then is quickly replaced with name search results). 
My questions are

1. I suspect I need to call some cleanup code on the view before it is re-used.  Where is the proper place within a backbone application to run this.
2. Is there anything wrong with the way I load SearchResults view from within RecordSearch view?  SearchResults does not have a path on my router, but it is basically a form post, so I assume it shouldn't?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are correct that you should handle view life cycles, but given your setup, this doesn't seem to be your problem. You perform `this.$el.html()` between view renders, so old views should not be making reappearances. To dig a little deeper, how does one go from a search result to a new search?

Comment: Do you have more than one element on the page with the "content" class? It seems strange that *everything* gets rendered in the same ".conent" element.

Comment: @Seebiscuit, thanks, I see what you mean .  I was misunderstanding the way backbone rendered content into the view's Element.  This was an issue in my code, but the major issue was the zombie view problem suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is quite common and is known as Zombie Views. Derick Bailey explains this issue very well here: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

However unfortunately you can't simply solve it without changing the way you are loading your views.

Because you are loading them inside RequireJS modules that will keep it in the local var scope, you are losing the reference to the views once the route has been fully processed.

In order to solve this problem, you would need to keep the reference of the current view somewhere, and then properly dispose it before calling another view, something like this:

```
showView: function(view) {
   this.currentView && this.currentView.remove();
   this.currentView = view;
   this.currentView.render();
   $('#content').html(this.currentView.el);
}
```

More about this solution here: http://tiagorg.com/talk-backbone-tricks-or-treats-html5devconf/#/6

I personally suggest you adopting a solution that will take care of this for you, like [Marionette.js](http://marionettejs.com)

It will handle this and quite many other issues, by providing the missing gaps of every Backbone-based architecture.

Comment: Your point is a very valid one, and I second your suggestion that the OP should go with Marionette,. However he's not reporting the common zombie complaint: multiple event triggering. So I think they may be other flaws with his code.

Comment: RequireJs and its is not in and of itself a problem. RequireJs callbacks still respect function closure and another context can always be accessed through this closure. I wouldn't suggest a whole code rewrite.

Comment: My problems were caused by zombie views, and I went with an approach similar to this. I have one class that handles all of the rendering of each view, so they can always be properly destroyed.

Comment: That is great, Ronnie! When destroying views, please be wary of unbinding events from models/collections as well - that needs to be done manually and will prevent your view to be garbage collected if the model/collections still has even bindings to the view. (Marionette.js would also take care of that for you)